# Will logzilla installation stop the old log file

Tags: ubuntu, log-files

I have installed logzilla for monitoring the logs and its is storing logs in

mysql database.

I want to know that will my logs now only get entered in mysql or i can access them as normal as well

like /var/log/messages

Comment: Are there new entries still appearing in /var/log/messages and so on? Are the possible new entries the same than the ones in MySQL? If so, then it's logging to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the rules :>

Logzilla is just to view the logs that has been saved into the database. But somehow these logs must be redirected there. That's where syslogd and it's derivatives (syslog-ng rsyslog) take their positions.

The big question is ... how do you place the logs into the database ? Could you send a sample of the configuration ? What do you use ? syslogd ? syslog-ng ? rsyslog ?

Comment: i used syslog-ng

Comment: ok. could you send me the configuration ? Otherwise i cannot tell if you save them both on the disk and the database.

Comment: where is the config file located

Comment: /etc/syslog.conf